# Modifying the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI post application launch

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have built a flask application and I would like to take configuration via a web form. This configuration would be the initial DB setup details etc.

I know the application will launch witout a functioning DB as I have made sure all page checks take this into account. I am able to capture the relevant details via the web form however, what I can not work out and can not find online is how do I modify the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`, in fact how do I modify any of the `app.config` variables and restart the application to initialise the new DB strings?

Comment: This was not answerd in the question you suggested and it seems my last comment was deleted off here. I have now solved ths problem, thank you for your help. Very helpful

Comment: Would be great if I could put an answer on it.